# VS2010 Data -> Schema Comparison duplicate files

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, schema, data-comparison

From time to time it would seem the Schema Comparison tool creates a new file for an existing table/view and swaps it out of the Database project for the old one.  For example:

Original file:

```
MyViewName.view.sql
```

New file:

```
MyViewName_1.view.sql
```

The original file remains on disk, but the database project references the new one instead.  Does anyone know why this occurs and how I can stop it?  (Wreaks havoc when comparing svn branches)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have the same problem...

When the file is already left on disk in your workspace and the schema compare tries to write a new table "MyViewName.view.sql" to disk, it finds a file that already exists and decides to create a new one vs overwriting the one on disk.

I do not know if this is a VS 2010 issue...if it's by design because of how workspaces work or if it's an issue with the database project itself.

I'm hoping someone else can offer a better explanation.

What I had to do for a workaround was delete the files from disk and redo the compare.

One thing you could do is use the power tools:
[In Visual Studio remove local files when undo pending changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260295/in-visual-studio-remove-local-files-when-undo-pending-changes)